# Create dynamic template with pipes?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-pipe

Following tutorial on creating dynamic templates in Angular 2 : [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009)

I managed to create dynamic component, but when i try to add pipe (exponentialStrength) inside template it breakes with following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'exponentialStrength' could not be found
```

I also tryed to add several pipes on authors [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wh4VJG?p=preview) code preview, but it shows same error.

Is there way to implement pipe while creating dynamic template?

This is my html template:

```
  <div  [style]="ContentCss | safeCss">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="Disabled" [(ngModel)]="Entity[FieldName]" >
  </div>
```

and component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { SafeHtml, SafeCss } from '../Components/sanitizeHtml.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'textbox',
    templateUrl: './textbox.component.html',
})
export class Textbox {

    @Input() public Entity: any;
    @Input() public Disabled: boolean;


}
```

pipe (error shows even with angular2 default pipes):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })
export class SafeHtml implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(html) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html); 
    }
}

@Pipe({ name: 'safeCss', pure:false })
export class SafeCss implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(style) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the module?
You need to `import { ExponentialStrength } from './somewhere/'exponentialstrength-pipe'`

Comment: @Swoox i just edited post with code example

Comment: show the code where you create a dynamic component

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com i was following tutorial, error can be simulated on authors plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wh4VJG?p=preview , by adding uppercase pipe in template of file app/parts/string.ts

Comment: it's huge answer with irrelevant code, show what you use exactly in your case. this article  [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) shows how this should be done